# "Unparseable date" using SimpleDateFormatter with API code example

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse dates, for example `"Sat, 29 Dec 2012 04:07:09 +0100"`
I am using SimpleDateFormatter with format set as

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.getDefault());
```

Unfortunately I am getting

```
12-29 04:44:29.890: E/MainActivity(3995): Unparseable date: "Sat, 29 Dec 2012 04:07:09 +0100" (at offset 0)
12-29 04:44:29.890: E/MainActivity(3995): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat, 29 Dec 2012 04:07:09 +0100" (at offset 0)
```

Which I absolutely dont get as that parameter regular expression is copy and pasted directly from documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html under Examples

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://ideone.com/Jj0v36 ... Can you show the whole code you use to parse it? What locale are you in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatever the locale returned by `Locale.getDefault()` is doesn't support dates formatted that way.

Changing it to `Locale.US` for example, will work.