# Convert string to date Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert a String that represents a date stored in SQLITE.

The date was stored into sqlite as follows:

```
Date date;

date.toString();
```

According with Java documentation, `toString()` method:

> Returns a string representation of this Date. The formatting is
>   equivalent to using a SimpleDateFormat with the format string "EEE MMM
>   dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", which looks something like "Tue Jun 22 13:07:00
>   PDT 1999". The current default time zone and locale are used. If you
>   need control over the time zone or locale, use SimpleDateFormat
>   instead.

Until here, it's fine but, when I try to get the String and convert it to date again, Java throws an exception.

The String comes from sqlite:

```
Mon Jan 20 18:26:25 BRT 2014
```

So, I do:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);

Date date= sdf.parse("Mon Jan 20 18:26:25 BRT 2014");
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't told us what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: Sorry! I need to get the date in this format: "dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: And what did you try to achieve that? The code above does not throw exceptions.

Comment: For me, the code above throws an exception. "java.text.ParseException". Unparseable Date "Mon Jan 20 00:00:00 BRT 2014" (at offset 0).

Comment: For me this code work, show us exception.

Comment: Did you try: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246936/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-at-offset-0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078523/unparseable-date-using-simpledateformatter-with-api-code-example

Comment: @vitorvigano By the way, that is the **absolute wrong way to store date-time data** in your database. Never use "toString" on java.util.Date except for quick-and-dirty purposes; it uses default time zone when you should be using UTC/GMT, and it uses 3-letter time zone codes which are neither standardized nor unique. Read the SQLite [doc on data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Use the SQLite [date-time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to store and retrieve in [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) adjusting to UTC/GMT (no time zone offset).

Comment: this is a wonderful way! worked for me!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14078523/642706

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
String dateString = "here your date";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Comment: This answer seems to have it upside down: it inputs the output format and outputs the input format.

Comment: Sure. "Mon Jan 20 18:26:25 BRT 2014"

Comment: i try with same format but without "BRT" it work with me , if you can remove BRT from your format ?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String w = "Mon Jan 20 18:26:25 BRT 2014";
SimpleDateFormat pre = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try{
    Date date = pre.parse(w);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
20/01/2014
```

Comment: I need to get a string "Mon Jan 20 18:26:25 BRT 2014" and convert to "dd/MM/yyyy". Your answer is not right.

Comment: You are receiving it strictly as a String or Date?

Comment: I'm receiving a string.

Answer (score 0):

Formatter for storing and restoring data value in format `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Storing data

```
String dataAsString = simpleDateFormat.format(date); // 20/01/2014
```

Restoring data

```
Date data = simpleDateFormat.parse(dataAsString);
```