# How to parser string to date with "Wed, 01 Jul 2015 17:32:41 EDT

Tags: java, android, date, formatter

Here is code to parser "Wed, 01 Jul 2015 17:32:41 EDT", but it still doesn't work. 
Does anyone can help me figure it out? many thanks.

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    try {
        return formatter.parse(text);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is not working, are you getting any exception

Comment: Just change to  `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");`

Comment: this is my exception:java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 02 Jul 2015 02:28:39 EDT" (at offset 0)

Comment: Just change to above line as I mentioned, that should fix the problem

Comment: I've try, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you returning the parsed text. post that too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to date Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244760/convert-string-to-date-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    try {
        System.out.println(formatter.parse("Wed, 01 July 2015 17:32:41 EDT"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

**Output :** Thu Jul 02 03:02:41 IST 2015

Answer (score 0):

You have a `,` after Wed... You need to account for that as well in the format...

Use `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"`

Comment: here is exception : java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 02 Jul 2015 02:28:39 EDT" (at offset 0)

Comment: Did it give the error even after adding the comma??? It is working perfectly fine for me...

Comment: I think it should be `"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"` i.e. add `'` around the comma as it it's not a recognised data symbol

Comment: @Onheiron... It doesn't make a difference... Special characters like comma, colon, space don't require quote around them...

Answer (score 0):

Use comma AND locale (Thu is english):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    try {
        String s = "Wed, 01 Jul 2015 17:32:41 EDT";
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US); //Or Locale.ENGLISH
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));

        //Or set timeZone to GMT-4:00 because EDT is GMT-4:00
        //df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-04:00"));

        Date time = null;
        time = df.parse(s);
        System.out.println("Time = " + s);
        String parsed = df.format(time);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output is:

> Old = Wed, 01 Jul 2015 17:32:41 EDT