# Android: SimpleDateFormat ParseException in Arabic

Tags: android, localization, simpledateformat

I am parsing the date string but getting the parse exception in `Arabic` mode but works fine when the language in the app is set to `English`.

### ParseException

```
06-15 19:16:07.607: W/System.err(27340): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "6-15-2014" (at offset 2)
06-15 19:16:07.617: W/System.err(27340):    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

But this is parsing fine in English.

### Code

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse(detail.getContactBDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Can anyone please point out that what is missing? or in other languages what I can do to prevent these types of strings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by setting the `Locale.English` as the `default locale` for date parsing after reading the Stackoverflow thread ["Unparseable date" using SimpleDateFormatter with API code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078523/unparseable-date-using-simpledateformatter-with-api-code-example).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure "detail.getContactBDate()" would return the exact string '6-15-2014'?

I believe ,it has no relationship with your language setting. Because Java can handle internationalization very well.

Print out the string and recheck your argument.

Comment: Why its working in English mode because when i change the language, it works fine.

Comment: What do you mean " change the language"? Do you mean your computer setting?